# Citation showing "a" "b" like (2018a) and (2018b) when the author list is different

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, lyx, natbib

So the problem is that, even when the author list is different, it adds "a" "b" like 2018a and 2018b, if the first author is the same. This problem does not seem to happen if the article type is @techreport instead of @article.

[image]

This is the entire code.

```
% Preview source code

%% LyX 2.3.3 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,lmargin=3cm,rmargin=3cm}
\PassOptionsToPackage{natbib=true}{biblatex}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[unicode=true,pdfusetitle,
 bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=false,bookmarksopen=false,
 breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 1},backref=false,colorlinks=true]
 {hyperref}
\hypersetup{
 linkcolor=blue, urlcolor=blue, citecolor=blue}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{afterpage}

\usepackage{newunicodechar} 
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{FFFD}{?????}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%Code for citation in good style
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage[style=authoryear, uniquename=false, uniquelist=false, maxbibnames=99]{biblatex}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{}
\usepackage{hyperref}

% Just for demo
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{maxcitenames=1}

\DeclareFieldFormat{citehyperref}{%
  \DeclareFieldAlias{bibhyperref}{noformat}% Avoid nested links
  \bibhyperref{#1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{textcitehyperref}{%
  \DeclareFieldAlias{bibhyperref}{noformat}% Avoid nested links
  \bibhyperref{%
    #1%
    \ifbool{cbx:parens}
      {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
      {}}}

\savebibmacro{cite}
\savebibmacro{textcite}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \printtext[citehyperref]{%
    \restorebibmacro{cite}%
    \usebibmacro{cite}}}

\renewbibmacro*{textcite}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    ( not test {\iffieldundef{prenote}} and
      test {\ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}} )
    or
    ( not test {\iffieldundef{postnote}} and
      test {\ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{\value{citetotal}}} )
  }
    {\DeclareFieldAlias{textcitehyperref}{noformat}}
    {}%
  \printtext[textcitehyperref]{%
    \restorebibmacro{textcite}%
    \usebibmacro{textcite}}}

\makeatother

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{References_test2.bib}
\begin{document}
\begin{doublespace}
\citet*{suarez2018unintended}

\citet*{suarez2018testtesttest}

\citet*{last2018test1}

\citet*{last2018test2}
\end{doublespace}

\pagebreak{}

\printbibliography

\pagebreak
\end{document}
```

And Reference_test2.bib has this.

```
% Encoding: UTF-8

@techreport{suarez2018unintended,
  title={Test1},
  author={Su{\'a}rez Serrato, Juan Carlos and Einstein, Albert},
  year={2018},
  institution={Journal1}
}

@techreport{suarez2018testtesttest,
  title={Test2},
  author={Su{\'a}rez Serrato, Juan Carlos},
  year={2018},
  institution={Journal2}
}

@article{last2018test1,
  title={test1},
  author={Last, First and Lasttwo, Firsttwo},
  journal={Journal1},
  year={2018}
}

@article{last2018test2,
  title={test2},
  author={Last, First and Lasthi, Firsthi and Laster, Firster},
  journal={Journal2},
  volume={30},
  number={2},
  pages={47--60},
  year={2018}
}
@Comment{jabref-meta: databaseType:bibtex;}
```

Answer (score 5):

This is an interesting effect. It can be reproduced in the following reduced MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,
  maxbibnames=99,
  maxcitenames=1,
  uniquename=false,
  uniquelist=false,
  natbib=true]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{last2018test1,
  title   = {test1},
  author  = {Last, First and Lasttwo, Firsttwo},
  journal = {Journal1},
  year    = {2018},
}
@article{last2018test2,
  title   = {test2},
  author  = {Last, First and Lasthi, Firsthi and Laster, Firster},
  journal = {Journal2},
  volume  = {30},
  number  = {2},
  pages   = {47--60},
  year    = {2018},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\citet*{last2018test1}

\citet*{last2018test2}

\citet{last2018test1}

\citet{last2018test2}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Last and Lasttwo (2018b)//Last, Lasthi, and Laster (2018a)]

Clearly the 'a' and 'b' are not necessary to uniquely identify the entries.

The 'problem' here is the usage of the starred `natbib` compatibility command `\citet*`. In `natbib` compatibility mode `\citet*` produces the output of `\citet` (`\textcite` in `biblatex` speak) but with the full author list no matter what `maxcitenames` says.

Compare that with the output you would get from 'normal' `\citet`, which is

[image: Last et al. (2018b)//Last et al. (2018a)]

Here the 'a' and 'b' are necessary to be able to uniquely match the two citations to the bibliography entries.

---

Depending on the desired output there are several things you can do.

I would probably arrange things so that I don't have to use `\citet*` all the time. This could be done by dropping the `maxcitenames` and `uniquelist` options.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,
  maxbibnames=99,
  uniquelist=false,
  natbib=true]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{last2018test1,
  title   = {test1},
  author  = {Last, First and Lasttwo, Firsttwo},
  journal = {Journal1},
  year    = {2018},
}
@article{last2018test2,
  title   = {test2},
  author  = {Last, First and Lasthi, Firsthi and Laster, Firster},
  journal = {Journal2},
  volume  = {30},
  number  = {2},
  pages   = {47--60},
  year    = {2018},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\citet*{last2018test1}

\citet*{last2018test2}

\citet{last2018test1}

\citet{last2018test2}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Last and Lasttwo (2018)//Last, Lasthi, and Laster (2018)//Last and Lasttwo (2018)//Last, Lasthi, and Laster (2018)]

But if you want different output, maybe you need slightly different settings.

Comment: Thank you but I can't replicate your nice output. Could you try to fix my original code?

Comment: And does your solution make it possible for me to flexibly choose between "A et al. (2019)"  and "A, B, C, D, E (2019)" when there are 5 or more authors?

Comment: @user1849133 I suggest you try to get your example down to a more minimal example.

Comment: @user1849133 I'm not quite sure which result you expect, but in your original code you load `biblatex` twice (which does not error here, but is generally a very bad idea) and set some options not only in `\usepackage` but also with `\ExecuteBibliographyOptions`. If you simplify that to what I showed above, the result should be slightly more sane. With the settings here you should get "A et al. (2019)" with `\citet*` and "A, B, C, D and E (2019)" with `\citet*` (I don't think it is particularly useful to switch between these forms, because consistency is key in citations, but it's possible).